# appx via task sequence to Windows 10 LTSB?

Tags: sccm

Issue with Windows 10 LTSB only.

Appx deploys using application but not using task sequence.

Wondering if anyone has been able to deploy appx via task sequence to Windows 10 LTSB successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appx packages are installed per user and therefore can't be installed via a task sequence. I've tried in the past to install the Appx using Powershell & DISM as part of a task sequence but neither method worked.

Check this link under the Install Application section:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/system-center-2012-R2/hh846237(v=technet.10)

Only way I found was to deploy the Appx to All Users as a required application.